Spring mongotemplate: How can i do projection of fields and provide alias to fields
I am have very simple requirement, where through MongoTemplate I am trying to filter and provide output. While providing output i need to change the column names through alias.
'''
Query query = new Query().allowDiskUse(true);
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("column1").is("yes") .....
Now through query.fields().include() i can do projection, but how can give different name to resulting column like alias
'''

Not sure If I'm understood correctly but I think you can use a simple aggregation pipeline.
Check this documentation to use projection.
So I think you can try something like this (not tested):
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    match(Criteria.where("column1").is("yes")),
    project().and("column1").as("your alias here")
);

